# Ubuntu 22.04 Firefox (snap) does not save session

Tags: firefox, snap, session

I am using Firefox supplied as snap, and overall it works ok, but one major thing that doesn't work is session saving. I have set the option in Firefox to restore tabs and windows on startup, but it never happens. What is worse, is that the History menu does not offer a Restore Previous Session possibility.

Looking in ~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox//sessionstore-backups there are files called previous.jsonlz4, recovery.baklz4, recovery.jsonlz4, and some upgrade.jsonlz4- files, so something is saved. I just cannot make firefox load it again.

Firefox does save my windows in the history and allows me to reopen them, but it does not save my session.

If I open History menu and select Manage History, I get a window where I can see the session I want under Import and Backup->Restore-><list of dates, size, and number of items>. But when I select the one I want, I just get a bunch of windows that say:

"No Apps available"/"No apps installed that can open "...ttps://www.mozilla.org/firefox/central/". You can find more applications in Software.

Is this a bug with the snap version of Firefox? It is unusable as a production browser for me in its current state when it loses stuff being restarted.

Comment: If you thin it is a bug you need to report it to the Firefox people.

Comment: But is this a firefox bug or a snap bug?

Comment: If you think it is a snap bug report it to the Snap people.

Comment: Reported it to Firefox. Firefox is called "Mozilla Firefox Snap for Ubuntu". Hmm may have to report it to cannonical as well I think.

Comment: Workaround : Uae apt version https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem on snap-provided Firefox: When I open History, select Manage History, and select a Restore point, it seems to  works properly and without error. It might be a bug...it might not. If it cannot be reproduced in a test environment, it likely cannot be identified and fixed.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. If you can, then add the specific list of steps to reproduce to your bug report.

Comment: Whether it is a Firefox bug or a Snap bug seems irrelevant, since the Firefox snap is produced by Mozilla developers (not Canonical engineers). Snap-related Firefox bugs should go to Mozilla for triage. Firefox-related snap  bugs should go to the same place for the same reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22)

Comment: I think that is more of a work-around; one that I may have to use. I have used a different work-around, namely installed a session manager in Firefox. I haven't tested this yet. Or I can delete my profile and start fresh (some people report this to work).